# Make some categories un-searchable in Magento search bar

Tags: php, magento, search, categories

I am working on a Magento theme. I am new to Magento. On my website the search bar is working fine but we have removed some product categories from the website. So I want to make these categories un-searchable. I don't know how to do this? They are are still searchable. I am working with the Magento admin panel. Please help me solve this problem. What steps should I take next?

Some categories give me this error

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object in /home/...../template/catalog/layer/view.phtml on line 122
```

Comment: Can you provide us some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These aren't the categories you're looking for.

Magento searches for products when you use the search bar, categories are only attributes here.
It wouldnt be consistent to look for categories : product A is in category C1 and C2. C1 is forbidden in search, what happens then?

Instead of that, you can setup searchability for each product.
In product admin page, in **General** tab, check for **Visibility** field and select **`Catalog`**.
Product won't appear on search results (don't forget to reindex after that).

You can also do this for a bunch of products using mass actions on **Manage Products** page. Select products you want to edit, then on action dropdown (top right) select **`Update Attributes`**. On next page you can change visibility for all those products.

Comment: @baooutch Thanks, Please tell which one option I have to reindex. There is lots of option.

Comment: Reindexing Catalog Search Index should do the trick. If you also changed some categories attributes you can reindex Catalog Category/Product Index. And in all cases, there is no harm in reindexing all options.

Answer (score 0):

If you "removed" categories from admin panel, it should not be searchable, however, if indexes are stale and not reindexed before you search again, it can "be searched". Run a indexer.php to reindex all.

```
php indexer.php --reindexall
```

Run this command at /shell directory